# Dependency Injection across assemblies & namespaces

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I am working on a DI problem that I think I understand the cause of, but I need some suggestions to work around.

I have built a stand alone assembly that talks to Sql (call this assembly a), and another assembly that contains business logic (call this assembly b). I created an interface for the db class in the b assembly. Since the interface isn't part of the db assembly, I don't need any references to the db project, and I can load a reference to the db assembly or a stub if I want to run unit tests at run time and neither assembly needs to know about the other.

I can write code in the business logic library that compiles that looks like this: (pretend that a and b are namespaces in their respective assemblies)

```
 a.IDatabaseClass db_class = (a.IDatabase)new b.Database();
```

When I try to run this however, I get an invalid cast exception. I think it compiles because the interface matches the class perfectly, but fails at run time because object signature doesn't see IDatabase in the inheritance chain of the Database class.

In c++ you can get away with casting anything however you want, but c# is a little bit stricter about casting object pointers. Even though the class has all the correct function signatures, it is blowing up because the objects don't match.

Now I could put the db object interface in the assembly with the db object, but then the business logic needs a reference to the db assembly. Also, this just creates complications down the road, because if I write a stub db object in a unit test, I need a reference to the db assembly just for the interface that I am going to use in my test stub object. This doesn't seem to be disentangling couplings by doing this...

I could put all the interfaces in a third assembly that is a parent to the db assembly, the business logic, and the unit tests. This is how you can solve circular dependency issues. However, this ties the db assembly to the parent assembly, and makes it a lot less modular to be used with other projects.

I am open to suggestions about how I can set up each assembly so that they function independently and can be used for DI. I suppose I could keep the test stub objects in the same assembly as the real code, but that seems weird.

**The Solution**

One of the replies below makes the comment that what I was shooting for is basically duck-typing for interfaces. C# doesn't support duck typing currently, but I was thinking it might be possible since interface implementation acts in similar way to what you might call a partial class pointer (or probably more accurately, a collection of function pointers). My experiment was showing me otherwise, and that is why.

So until Redmond puts 'more mallard' into c#, looks like we cannot reach that final elegant level of decoupling assemblies entirely.

Comment: Can you confirm that the sql library is referencing the business logic library? And that `b.Database` implements `a.IDatabase`? Or, are the libraries strictly independent?

Comment: It appears after reading the post again that they're completely independent libraries. I would definitely go for the '3rd library' approach. It's definitely the cleanest, and I don't really agree that referencing a library merely exposing interfaces is creating a tight coupling of your sql library.

Comment: You are correct, they are both independent (or could be) independent of each other. I was hoping to be able to use DI to completely disconnect either assembly from needing the other, and either an exe or unit test would pipe data around at run time. It appears that c#'s attempts to make my code safer with strong typing is preventing me from achieving this ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a reference library containing your common interfaces. This way you'll have a common source with all of your implementation agnostic logic.

I don't have the experience to feel confident making this a categorical statement, but I strongly suspect that coupling is primarily an issue when you're talking about individual types referencing specific interfaces and how they behave. Assemblies don't have the same sort of specificity that would make coupling a problem.

## Edit 1

Let me amend and extend. One assembly must reference the other, or both must reference a common assembly. C# doesn't have duck-interfacing, if that's a thing.

Now I think the best practice is to isolate the business logic from external interfaces, so if you're going to do anything you should keep your business logic isolated from your DB implementation. So DB/Application assembly references business logic, but not the other way around.

[Here's more information about the dependency orientation](http://tpierrain.blogspot.ca/2013/08/a-zoom-on-hexagonalcleanonion.html).

Comment: That is probably the most succinct description of what I was hoping to achieve, 'duck-interfacing'.

Comment: Further notes on c# duck typing: http://ericlippert.com/2014/01/02/what-is-duck-typing/

Answer (score 3):

Let the client library (`b`) define the interface, and reference that library from the server library (`a`).

From the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) it follows that "clients [...] own the abstract interfaces" ([APPP](http://amzn.to/19W4JHk), chapter 11), so there's no reason to put the interface in a third library.

Comment: And that is exactly what I am trying to do. I was trying to be clever and do it without requiring the either assembly to depend on the other. I suspect that can cannot be done in c# in that fashion.

Comment: @MadTigger No, you can't do this in C#. I don't think you'd be able to do it in Java either.

Comment: There is a reason to put the interface in another third library: If there is a many-to-many relationship: Alice does a game Alice.Invaders (client), and puts an "in-app purchases shop-plugin" Alice.Shop (implementation). The shop should be replaceable by other shops (for example plug Bob.Shop). Still those shops should be pluggable into other games. No sense that Charlie.Pacman references interfaces in Alice.Invaders, so a third namespace lis Alice.Shop.Interfaces is needed.

Comment: See what @MaDeRkAn answered me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688838/c-sharp-namespacing-for-interfaces-in-dependency-injection/35694979#35694979 - I had a similar question.

Comment: In fact from the article you reference, it secifically says: "Nevertheless the ″inversion″ concept does not mean that lower-level layers depend on higher-level layers. Both layers should depend on abstractions that draw the behavior needed by higher-level layers." - So yes, third namespace with interfaces.