# C# namespacing for interfaces in dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface, namespaces, dependencies

I want to use the `Dependency Injection` pattern in C#, and I want to have the logics as separated as possible in namespaces.

## Question

In which namespace should the `interface` of the consumed class be?

## Motivation of the question

First let's do some "normal" case. A book-case to be used as the basis for the second part of the explanation. Then, the "real-life" case, which arises the question.

### Book case

Let's assume the coder is Alice and that she uses `Alice` as a top-level name in the namespaces as a vendor, to avoid any conflict with other coders. For this example, we'll assume there are no other Alices in the world.

Let's assume she creates 3 namespaces:

- `Alice.Invaders` - a game that shall provide in-app purchases via a shop.
- `Alice.Shop` - a reusable shop for several games.
- `Alice.Injector` - a reusable service manager.

Let's assume the `Shop` project has an `interface` named `IShopService` which provides a method `Show()`.

Let's assume the `Invaders` has some kind of controller that at some user-action wants to open the shop.

Let's assume the services, like the `Shop`, are gotten via a `ServiceManager` by the controller of the `Invaders`.

#### Alice.Injector

The `Alice.Injector` itself is an independent project that has no dependencies, so it does not use the "using" keyword:

```
namespace Alice.Injector
{
    public interface IService
    {
        // All the services shall implement this interface.
        // This is necessary as C# is heavily typed and the
        // Get() method below must return a known type.
    }

    public class ServiceManager
    {
        static public IService Get( string serviceName )
        {
            IService result;

            // Do the needed stuff here to get the service.
            // Alice implements this getter configurable in a text-file
            // so if she wants to test the invaders with a mock-shop
            // that does not do real-purchases but fake-ones
            // she can swap the injected services without changing the
            // consumer's code.

            result = DoTheNeededStuff();

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Alice.Shop

The `Alice.Shop` is also an independent project which (except in the case it consumes services) is not aware of the existance of an injector. Just is a shop and that's it.

As Alice thinks that maybe Bob will make some better shop someday, she prepares her class to be dependency-injected, following the separation of the `Shop` into an interface `IShop` and then the implementation, following this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh323705%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

To achieve that, Alice will make the shop to be a service kind of compatible with the `Alice.ServiceManager`, so Alice decides that the `IShop` will be renamed to `IShopService` and it will be a kind of `IService`.

```
using Alice.Injector

namespace Alice.Shop
{
    public interface IShopService : IService
    {
        public void Show();
    }

    public class Shop : IShopService
    {
        public void Show()
        {
            // Here Alice puts all the code to open the shop up.
        }
    }
}
```

#### Alice.Invaders

Finally, Alice codes the game. The code of the `Alice.Invaders` gets a `Shop` (that takes the shape of a service) via the `ServiceManager` so it is all clean-code.

```
using Alice.Injector
using Alice.Shop

namespace Alice.Invaders
{
    public class DefaultController
    {
        void OnShopClick()
        {
            IShopService shop = ServiceManager.Get( "Shop" ) as IShopService;
            shop.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Up to here, this all works nicely.

### Real-life case

So now... Bob (a good friend of Alice, as you all know, curious that they don't talk about sending encripted messages today), does a super-nice shop that is even nicer than the one that Alice did. Bob does his shop from scratch.

So Bob implements the shop compatible with Alice's injector (as Bob also uses the `Alice.Injector` for injecting other stuff in his projects).

```
using Alice.Injector

namespace Bob.Shop
{
    public interface IShopService : IService
    {
        public void Show();
    }

    public class Shop : IShopService
    {
        public void Show()
        {
            // Here Bob does a brand new shop from scratch.
        }
    }
}
```

So... here it is the weird situation!!

- **`Bob.Shop` Namespace for the interface** - If Bob does his shop inside the `Bob.Shop` namespace the way displayed above, then Alice *must* edit her code to reference `Bob.Shop` to get the `IShopService` interface (ugly she has to change the dependency in the code, as it was supposed to use Dependency Injectors to get rid of changing the dependencies in the code).
- **No namespace for the interface** - If both Alice and Bob setup the `IShopService` in the global namespace, it is ugly too, as there is much things that could conflict there.
- **`Alice.Shop` Namespace for the interface** - If Bob makes use of common sense and says "What I want to do is to create a shop **compatible** with Alice's one, then I should implement HER interface" so Bob's code most likely will be like this one:

Bob's code using `Alice.Shop` backwards namespace compatibility:

```
namespace Bob.Shop
{
    public class Shop : Alice.Shop.IShopService
    {
        public void Show()
        {
            // Here Bob does a brand new shop from scratch,
            // which borrows Alice's interface.
        }
    }
}
```

In this case it seems everything is in place:

- Bob may create the `Bob.Shop.Shop` that implements the `Alice.Shop.IShopService`
- Alice does not need to change a single line of code.
- The `Alice.Injector.ServiceManager` is able to provide another `IService` when serving the `Bob.Shop.Shop`.

## Problem

Still there is a dependency here:

`Alice.Invaders` is casting the `Alice.Injector.IService` to an `Alice.Shop.IShopService` in order to be able to call the `Show()` method. If you don't do that cast, you can't "show the shop".

So at the end, you are "depending" on that cast and therefore "someone" needs to provide you the interface definition.

If the original shop was not written by Alice, but by Charlie, it would be "ugly" to still have to download and keep a copy of the `Charlie.Shop` project in order to use `Bob.Shop`.

So...

## Questions

1) What is the correct namespace for `IShopInterface` to live in?

2) Does the "replacement" project provide it's own interface or borrow the original one?

3) Should maybe the original shop be splitted in TWO projects? (like for example `Alice.Shop` and `Alice.ShopImplementation` so `Alice.Shop` is veeery slim and only contains the interfaces? Maybe `Alice.Shop` and `Alice.Shop.Implementation` as a nested namespace, but still two sepated code-bases so you can download ans install `Alice.Shop` without downloading `Alice.Shop.Implementation`?

4) Is that as simple as Bob does include a copy of `Alice.Shop.IShopInterface` file in his project so no dependencies are needed? Very ugly - if he does so and we want to have the 2 shops and send the users to one or other shop, that would conflict.

Thanks.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080019/dependency-injection-across-assemblies-namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces, injector and implemantation should be in different namespaces. Interfaces should be in `Alice.Shop.Interfaces` and there shouldn't be any implemantation in this namespace. You can change/hide implementation, but you should stick with Interfaces in dependency Injection.

> Alice.Invaders is casting the Alice.Injector.IService to an
>   Alice.Shop.IShopService in order to be able to call the Show() method.
>   If you don't do that cast, you can't "show the shop".

Your DefaultController implemantation is not good. If I want to use it, I don't know anything about which services I need. It says to me, I don't need anything now.

You should use constructor injection.

```
public class DefaultController
 {
   private readonly IShopService _shopService;

   DefaultController(IShopService shopService)
   {
     _shopService=shopService;
   }

   void OnShopClick()
   {
     _shopService.Show();
   }
  }
```

If I need defaultcontroller, I would know which services I need with this implemantation. And you don't need to cast.

**Edit:**

Let's say Alice has a shop. She says I want a reading room which has 5 chairs. But she will decide chairs are from wood or leather (IChairs). When she openes the shop, she decides to use wood chairs (Inject WoodChairs for IChairs).

Then Bob buys the shop from Alice. He can't change reading room (it's hard it will take time and reading room is just fine). But he wants leather chairs so he uses leather chairs (Inject LeatherChairs for IChairs).

Bob should stick `Alice.Shop.Interfaces` if he can't or doesn't want to change Reading Room.

But let's say. I like Alice Reading Room much. I want to design a reading room like hers. But I want to make my rules for Reading Room (IMyReadingRoom adapter, you get ReadingRoom class not Interface and you create your own interfaces).

**In short**: You should stick interfaces always. You can create your own Interface ([Adapter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774259/Adapter-Design-Pattern-Csharp)) for 3rd party libraries. That's way you can extend or hide the rules without stick to 3rd party library (But you should stick with your own Interface anyway). You should write adapter for 3rd party library implemantation not for their interfaces.

If we skip adapter choice Bob has to use `Alice.Shop.Interfaces` for injecting.

Comment: Ah yes! So, interfaces in a different namespace. Got it. I agree at "injecting" the IShopService in the constructor, so you get the proper type without casting... But, still, for this to compile, I need to put the `using Alice.Shop.Interfaces` in the top, otherwise the compiler won't know what's `IShopService`, right?

Comment: So you mean: Bob may declare his own `Bob.Shop.Interfaces.IShopService` which in fact inherits from `Alice.Shop.Interfaces.IShopService`. So from Bob's application point of view, Bob consumes only Bob's interface `Bob.Shop.Interface.IShopService`, despite it is "at least compatible" to Alice's. So, if Bob's application does a `using Alice.Shop.Interfaces`, Bob can both use Alice's shops and Bob's shops. If Bob does a `using Bob.Shop.Interfaces` then Bob can use his own shops, and Alice's via a Bob's wrapper. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Let's say Alice has important class which uses `IShopService`. Bob wants to use this important class. That's way he can't change `IShopService` injection. He should inject `Alice.Shop.Interfaces.IShopService`. Because this important class just knows `Alice.Shop.Interfaces.IShopService`. But if bobs says in future I want to change `Alice.Shop.Interfaces.IShopService` may be extend also important clas, then bob should use adapter. In Adapter Bob creates New Class and assign his own interface. When bob's class show executes it actually calls this important class shows in adapter.

Comment: Okey, undertood. So assuming he wants to be Alice-compatible and do not use an adapter, in your example in the answer, in the code, a text line saying `using Alice.Shop.Interfaces` should still be needed to frame "which `IShopService` we are using", correct? - maybe edit the answer to add it?

Comment: Microsoft itself does not put interfaces in another namespace, but does often put them in another library (.abstractions) for .net core libraries